# How can I secure my source code

Tags: php, security

I am writing a php product, What I am thinking if I provide source code to all of them they can create their own copy, I don't want to create license key functionality if its valid it will activate because good coder knows how to void license, is there any way to encode php code not to read by any one if they already source?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Royal Bg mentions in the comments, if they have the source code, there's no way you can secure it against them making a separate copy. As you mention, any attempt at a licence key, or any other type of method, they'd be able to get around.